# How nested lists works or append to a list in Cloudformation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I want to refer the security that is getting created in the stack itself. I am trying this but nothing gets worked. Can someone help me out.

```
Parameters:
  env:
    Default: qa
    Type: String
```

Here are the mappings

```
Mappings:
  envMap:
    qa:
      securityGroups: 'sg-xxxxxxxx,sg-xxxxxxxx'
    sub:
      subnets: 'subnet-xxxxxxxx,subnet-xxxxxxxx'
```

I am creating Security Group and also want to map existing security groups as well.

```
Resources:

  InstanceSecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: Allow http to client host
        SecurityGroupIngress:
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 80
            ToPort: 80
            CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  LoadBalancer:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      SecurityGroups: !Split
        - ','
        - !Sub
          - '!Ref InstanceSecurityGroup,${mappedGroup}'
          - mappedGroup: !FindInMap
              - envMap
              - !Ref env
              - securityGroups
      Subnets: !Split
        - ','
        - !FindInMap
          - envMap
          - sub
          - subnets
```

Comment: Are these in 2 different yaml files? (Essentially 2 different stacks) or a single yaml file with all of it?

Comment: All are in single yaml file..